# How to build .deb .rpm .dmg etc with one script

Tags: debian, rpm

Here is my problem:

I have a program and would like to distribute it in binary format so that users don't need to compile it by themselves.

I have already build a .deb package. However, as I remember, there should be some program, which takes one configuration file, and produces different binary packages in different formats, like .deb, .rpm, or even .dmg, .msi, etc. Meaning, I only need to tell it which file should be included in the package (and how to build it), it can produce different packages for me.

After googling some key words, I noticed it's hard to find such program without knowing its name. (I do think there should be something like that. In fact, I remembered I saw it in somewhere.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effing Package Management can do both rpm and deb (get it from
https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm)

For cross-platform deployments of the sort you are talking about, you could try http://project-builder.org/

*Note - I never used these tools but I've heard of them

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is wrong in my opinion. Your job as a developer is to develop the program, not package it for all different Linux distributions. Let distributions handle packaging. Since your knowledge of their packaging guidelines is non-existent you will likely create binary packages which can fail in spectacular ways on some systems and what's worse...can even break users' systems.

What you **can** do however:

- Make sure licensing is clear and simple (preferably one of OSI-approved licenses)
- List your dependencies, including versions and do not bundle them
- Have sane update policices (i.e. mini/micro version updates don't break APIs or introduce huge changes)
- Use one of standard build systems (depending on the project it can be autotools, setup.py, maven etc.)
- Ideally do not do weird stuff, but learn how some nice projects do things (Apache project usually have sensible approach)
- **Then** contact the distributions and try to get some packages interested in maintaining your program

Comment: Would be nice to know why the -1...maybe I could learn something along the way. Oh well..

Comment: Sorry about that. But I didn't pressed -1 (I do not have enough reputation to down vote.) Thanks for your answer. (up vote for your answer, although @Srdjan's answer helps me the most.)

Comment: You are not answering the question, but challenging the question as such. This seems to be caused by your assumption that monnand wants to distribute his program via Linux distributions, which might not be the case (could be company internal as well, as devilish as that may be ;) ...). (I did not downvote by the way.)

Comment: @tssch You are correct, I assumed too much. I guess it was probably due to "so that users don't need to compile it by themselves". That triggered my packager experience brain synapses :-) I'll leave the answer be since I believe there's still some informational value